# Android - having troubles with MapView and ScrollView

Tags: android, android-mapview, scrollview, android-tabhost

Right now I'm having a really annoying problem. I have a `ScrollView` and inside the `ScrollView` I have a `TabHost` and inside of one of those tabs I have a `MapView`, the problem is that with that configuration the `MapView` fills the whole screen leaving out the tabs and what I want is just to fill the empty space below the tabs!

I have something like this:

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" > 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/white" >

<TabHost ..... >

<MapView ..... />

</TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If I remove the `ScrollView` everything works perfectly but removing it is not an option here!

Comment: "If I remove the ScrollView everything works perfectly but removing it is not an option here!" -- since `ScrollView` and `MapView` are not going to get along very well, removing the `ScrollView` not only is an option but probably a requirement. With respect to your question, since you elected to not show the portion of the layout that is the source of your difficulty (`TabHost` and *all* its contents, including the `MapView`), and you did not post the source code where you are populating your tabs, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to assist you.

Comment: thanks for your honesty CommonsWare, I really appreciate it! I kind of fix it but of course not the best way, I just put the scroll on top and disable the scrolling option when the user enter to the MapView, that way it will show the tabs and the map! Thanks anyway!